# Why can I gather herbs that require a higher level?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When I preordered WOD I got a character boost to level 90 and I used it on my level 21 Tauren druid. For professions I took herbalism and inscription. I trained these to level 100 and with the level 90 upgrade they also remained at their old level.

Now what kind of confuses me is the fact that I can gather herbs in pandaria. I have a herbalism skill of 109 but when I mouseover a Herb it says "Requires *level here*" in a light orange and if I click it my char actually gathers the plant.

Can someone explain to me why this works? Also is this herbalism only or is it the same for Mining etc.

By the way I only saw this in pandaria, so this might be just on the "new" continent. I haven't been to other places yet.

Comment: Well if it is orange you could still harvest it right? It has been years since i've played wow? But isn't it just like crafting? You can also make the orange colored items to certainly increase your level because yellow would sometimes give you a level or not... and so on... I think the same counts for gathering

Comment: Because both `Herbalism` and `Mining` was updated to work in this way. There is still a skill requirement to get the resources used by the higher skill levels and they are still seperate by zone if I am not mistaken. This change to these skills are well documented on the normal `World of Warcraft` fan pages.  `Skinning` was not changed.  There are also additional changes to these skills once the expansion is actually released.

Comment: @Lyrion yes but My herbalism skill is at 109 and I can collect stuff that is for level 550... this is what kinda confuses me.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh ok.. Well if you turn the comment into an answer I could accept it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both Herbalism and Mining was updated to work in this way. There is still a skill requirement to get the resources used by the higher skill levels and they are still seperate by zone if I am not mistaken. This change to these skills are well

Skinning was not changed in this round of changes that took place in the 5.3.x update.

There are also additional changes to these skills once the expansion (WOD) is actually released.

This is relativly new change to these skills, I believe you can find the summary of these changes, in one of the [previous patch notes](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/10021220/#professions).

Comment: Just an addition to your answer: This was changed with patch 5.3. : http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/10021220/#professions